# What is the difference in meaning of "dim-witted" and "stupid" in this context

Tags: word-choice

Instead of saying "You are more dim-witted than usual" could I say "You are more stupid than usual"?

Comment: Please tell us the results of your dictionary search.

Comment: I red this in a book

Comment: @coolguy - was this before you blue up a balloon?

Comment: I think "dim-witted" is rather old-fashioned.

Comment: @anouk - a little old-fashioned, but not howlingly so. Also it isn't very inclusive or respectful of diversity to use epithets like 'dim-witted', 'stupid', 'idiotic', etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, "dim-witted" and "stupid" usually mean pretty much the same thing.  "Stupid" is often a bit stronger or harsher.

"Dim-witted" means basically "not clever" or "not as smart as one could be", while "stupid" implies "not capable of thinking intelligently".